# Parsing XML in python with &lt and &gt characters ElementTree

Tags: python, xml, parsing, elementtree

I am using a public API and the response im getting from the API is

```
<string xmlns="http://ws.sdde.bccr.fi.cr">&lt;Datos_de_INGC011_CAT_INDICADORECONOMIC&gt;
  &lt;INGC011_CAT_INDICADORECONOMIC&gt;
    &lt;COD_INDICADORINTERNO&gt;3148&lt;/COD_INDICADORINTERNO&gt;
    &lt;DES_FECHA&gt;2016-01-01T00:00:00-06:00&lt;/DES_FECHA&gt;
    &lt;NUM_VALOR&gt;533.00000000&lt;/NUM_VALOR&gt;
  &lt;/INGC011_CAT_INDICADORECONOMIC&gt;
  &lt;INGC011_CAT_INDICADORECONOMIC&gt;
    &lt;COD_INDICADORINTERNO&gt;3148&lt;/COD_INDICADORINTERNO&gt;
    &lt;DES_FECHA&gt;2016-01-02T00:00:00-06:00&lt;/DES_FECHA&gt;
    &lt;NUM_VALOR&gt;533.00000000&lt;/NUM_VALOR&gt;
  &lt;/INGC011_CAT_INDICADORECONOMIC&gt;
&lt;/Datos_de_INGC011_CAT_INDICADORECONOMIC&gt;</string>
```

I am trying to parse that XML using ElementTree but it is not working, my assumption is that its not working beacuse of the `&lt` and `&gt` that are in the response instead of `<>` but even after replacing the xml parser still doesnt work

Any ideas?

The code im using:

```
response = requests.get(url)
cleaned_data = response.text.replace('&lt;','<')
cleaned_data = cleaned_data.replace('&gt;','>')
tree = ET.fromstring(cleaned_data)
print(tree)
```

Comment: Don't tell us something "isn't working". Tell us how it failed.

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find the reported error, using lib lxml or xml (built-in) with python3.9.

```py
import lxml.etree as ET
from pprint import pprint


xml_str = """
<string xmlns="http://ws.sdde.bccr.fi.cr">&lt;Datos_de_INGC011_CAT_INDICADORECONOMIC&gt;
  &lt;INGC011_CAT_INDICADORECONOMIC&gt;
    &lt;COD_INDICADORINTERNO&gt;3148&lt;/COD_INDICADORINTERNO&gt;
    &lt;DES_FECHA&gt;2016-01-01T00:00:00-06:00&lt;/DES_FECHA&gt;
    &lt;NUM_VALOR&gt;533.00000000&lt;/NUM_VALOR&gt;
  &lt;/INGC011_CAT_INDICADORECONOMIC&gt;
  &lt;INGC011_CAT_INDICADORECONOMIC&gt;
    &lt;COD_INDICADORINTERNO&gt;3148&lt;/COD_INDICADORINTERNO&gt;
    &lt;DES_FECHA&gt;2016-01-02T00:00:00-06:00&lt;/DES_FECHA&gt;
    &lt;NUM_VALOR&gt;533.00000000&lt;/NUM_VALOR&gt;
  &lt;/INGC011_CAT_INDICADORECONOMIC&gt;
&lt;/Datos_de_INGC011_CAT_INDICADORECONOMIC&gt;</string>
"""

cleaned_data = xml_str.replace("&lt;", "<")
cleaned_data = cleaned_data.replace("&gt;", ">").strip()
print("cleaned_data")
pprint(cleaned_data)

tree = ET.fromstring(cleaned_data)
print("\ntree")
print(tree)
pprint(ET.tostring(tree).decode())
```

Output:

```
cleaned_data
('<string '
 'xmlns="http://ws.sdde.bccr.fi.cr"><Datos_de_INGC011_CAT_INDICADORECONOMIC>\n'
 '  <INGC011_CAT_INDICADORECONOMIC>\n'
 '    <COD_INDICADORINTERNO>3148</COD_INDICADORINTERNO>\n'
 '    <DES_FECHA>2016-01-01T00:00:00-06:00</DES_FECHA>\n'
 '    <NUM_VALOR>533.00000000</NUM_VALOR>\n'
 '  </INGC011_CAT_INDICADORECONOMIC>\n'
 '  <INGC011_CAT_INDICADORECONOMIC>\n'
 '    <COD_INDICADORINTERNO>3148</COD_INDICADORINTERNO>\n'
 '    <DES_FECHA>2016-01-02T00:00:00-06:00</DES_FECHA>\n'
 '    <NUM_VALOR>533.00000000</NUM_VALOR>\n'
 '  </INGC011_CAT_INDICADORECONOMIC>\n'
 '</Datos_de_INGC011_CAT_INDICADORECONOMIC></string>')

tree
<Element {http://ws.sdde.bccr.fi.cr}string at 0x110446900>
('<string '
 'xmlns="http://ws.sdde.bccr.fi.cr"><Datos_de_INGC011_CAT_INDICADORECONOMIC>\n'
 '  <INGC011_CAT_INDICADORECONOMIC>\n'
 '    <COD_INDICADORINTERNO>3148</COD_INDICADORINTERNO>\n'
 '    <DES_FECHA>2016-01-01T00:00:00-06:00</DES_FECHA>\n'
 '    <NUM_VALOR>533.00000000</NUM_VALOR>\n'
 '  </INGC011_CAT_INDICADORECONOMIC>\n'
 '  <INGC011_CAT_INDICADORECONOMIC>\n'
 '    <COD_INDICADORINTERNO>3148</COD_INDICADORINTERNO>\n'
 '    <DES_FECHA>2016-01-02T00:00:00-06:00</DES_FECHA>\n'
 '    <NUM_VALOR>533.00000000</NUM_VALOR>\n'
 '  </INGC011_CAT_INDICADORECONOMIC>\n'
 '</Datos_de_INGC011_CAT_INDICADORECONOMIC></string>')
```